# Golang SSH Session commands too long to receive

Tags: go, ssh

I'm writing a script to back up the configuration file of various network devices through a go land script with the latest SSH package. For basic commands I can save the answer to a txt file, but for commands that give longer answers it doesn't complete the result or fail.

```golang
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func backupConfig(deviceIP, username, password string) error {
    var client *ssh.Client
    var err error

    // Try SSH connection first
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: username,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(password),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        Timeout:         30 * time.Second, // increase timeout to 30 seconds
    }

    client, err = ssh.Dial("tcp", deviceIP+":22", config)
    if err == nil {
        defer func(client *ssh.Client) {
            err := client.Close()
            if err != nil {

            }
        }(client)

        session, err := client.NewSession()
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to create session: %v", err)
        }
        defer func(session *ssh.Session) {
            err := session.Close()
            if err != nil {

            }
        }(session)

        var stdoutBuf, stderrBuf bytes.Buffer
        session.Stdout = &stdoutBuf
        session.Stderr = &stderrBuf

        err = session.Run("show ip int brief")
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to execute command: %v, stderr: %v", err, stderrBuf.String())
        }

        err = os.WriteFile(deviceIP+".txt", stdoutBuf.Bytes(), 0644)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to write backup file: %v", err)
        }

        return nil
    }
```

When I send a basic cisco command like show ip int brief it does receive the response and saves it, but for commands like show running-config or show startup-config it either returns and error message for the command not returning exit signal or receives the configuration partially and saves it, respectively.

Comment: My guess is that your receive buffer is full. You need to retrieve data from it asynchronously then. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].